Chain rule with functional derivatives?
I'd like to make the functional derivative of the functional $S[\phi(x)]$ with respect to the Fourier transform $\widetilde{\phi}(p)$ such that
$$\phi(x)=\int\frac{d^{d}p}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}e^{ip\cdot x}\widetilde{\phi}(p)$$
Can I use the following chain rule
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta\widetilde{\phi}(p)}[\phi]=∫{d^{d}x}\frac{\delta\phi(x)}{\delta{\widetilde{\phi}}(p)}\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}[\phi]=∫ \frac{d^{d}x}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}e^{ip\cdot x}\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}[\phi]$$
or not?

Sorry for vandalizing your question. I did not know your notation. I corrected it

Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/816635/2451
